# Creating replicated claims in WSO2 Identity Server

Tags: wso2, claims, wso2-identity-server

I am using wso2 Identity Server and creating custom claims in it. In a specific use case i need two claims to ***replicate*** the same value.
So while creating user if i have give "1234" to claim http://wso2.org/claims/store1/id1 than claim http://wso2.org/claims/store2/id2 should also have "1234".
Is there any way possible to achieve this.

Comment: If it is same value then why do you wanna have 2 claims?

Comment: Background: there are lot of user data that has to be imported into IS from a third party DB. So two tables can have primary key and foreign key relationship. 
To keep things simple  I am planning to have a claim format like http://wso2.org/calims/{tablename}/{cloumnname} and import all data. This is easy to implement and on a later stage well understandable relation between claims and DB. The problem might if a user add different values to claims in IS as there is no relation between two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to achieve this, is to overwrite method in user store manager. There you can put your custom logic to save and get  claims.

Comment: Well this is a kind of approach. But i was wounding if there anything possible in UI.

Comment: If you map the claim to same attribute of user store, it is possible. In that case, if you update one claim e.g. http://wso2.org/claims/store1/id1, changes will be reflected in all claims mapped to same attribute e.g. http://wso2.org/claims/store2/id2